# Use same preamble, title page and TOC across several files

Tags: templates, preamble

I realized that I use the same preamble across several files. These are mostly articles formatted in precisely the same --- headers, footers, margins, font, etc. Even the title page is formatted the same way --- contents change but the page structure remains the same.

My approach so far has been to copy paste from an earlier file. This works, but is not elegant.

Is there a better way? Some kind of a template file? So, I ask TeX to use the same template and everything is taken care of including the title page and TOC. Of course, I understand, I will need to provide title page details like author name, etc.

FWIW, I mostly use auctex on emacs. But have to use vim and co. occasionally.

Comment: You can just write the preamble in `mypreamble.tex`, say, and include it with `\input{mypreamble}` in the preambles of these files.

Comment: @marmot Thanks. How do I pass on variables like author names? Also, how do I set-up the title page and TOC? These two things come after the preamble

Comment: I do not understand the question. Just define the author and other stuff in the respective file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your preamble `mypreamble.tex` and save it (but without writind `\documentclass[...]{...}` as usual), then on your main file you write `\documentclass[...]{...}` and immediatly after you define `\title{My title}`, `\author{Me}`,... and then you input your preamble with `\input{myoreamble.tex}`. I hope this helps